# Generic xml -> html conversion using xslt and convention?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have been scouring the web for something like this and being a lazy programmer, before I attempt to do so myself, I thought I would ask here.

What I would like is a method to take any xml with node names following a convention (like cakephp or ruby) and then for that data to be presented in a ready to print format.

ie:

```
<xml>
<home_address>The Street</home_address>
</xml>
```

to:

```
<tr><td>Home Address</td><td>The Street</td></tr>
```

etc. with children having separate tables.

It seems pretty straightforward and something that would have been desired many times before. I found one useful discussion, but with no conclusion.

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/xml-xslt-and-xpath/threads/363621/xml-to-html-using-xslt-without-hardcoding-node-names-in-xslt

Have I missed something here? Is there a simple generic xslt/css method for doing this? Or is this work being repeated hundreds of times a day in cubicles around the world?

Thanks in advance,

F

Comment: Welcome to SO, though your question is too vague. What convention? Give us some example input XML and desired output. Please edit the question and someone may be able to help.

Comment: You need to think this one though, and come up with some rules of transformation. As it is, your question is just too vague to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following XSL stylesheet. I have tested it and it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <tr>
          <xsl:variable name="NodeNameClearText">
            <xsl:call-template name="repalceNodeName">
              <xsl:with-param name="value" select="local-name(.)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$NodeNameClearText" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </td>
            </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="repalceNodeName">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="valueWithoutUnderscores">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate($value, '_',' ')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="caseLowerAcceptFirstWord">
      <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$valueWithoutUnderscores"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="caseDown">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:if test="$data">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($data,' ')">
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="caseLowerAcceptFirstWord">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="normalize-space(substring($data,2))"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($data,1,1),
                                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
          <!-- put all the chars you want to change 
                 into the last two strings -->
          <xsl:call-template name="caseDown">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="caseUP">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:if test="$data">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($data,' ')">
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:call-template name="caseLowerAcceptFirstWord">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($data,1,1),
                                  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
          <!-- put all the chars you want to change 
                 into the last two strings -->
          <xsl:call-template name="caseDown">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="caseLowerAcceptFirstWord">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upperData">
      <xsl:call-template name="caseUP">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$upperData">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($upperData,1,1)"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="caseDown">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A little more info on what I tested. The following XML:

```
<xml>
<home_address>The Street</home_address>
<po_box>474</po_box>
</xml>
```

Was output to

```
<tr><td>Home Address</td><td>The Street</td></tr>
<tr><td>Po Box</td><td>474</td></tr>
```

If thats not what you wanted your question is to vague

Comment: Thanks James. That is what I was after. I'll go seek some points and vote this up. In the meantime I have converted the xml into a php array and recursively looped through that, but I prefer your xslt method.